# Switching innerHTML on return click event

Tags: javascript

I have this show more/less click event and It changes on the first click but I am not sure how to get it to return to the previous state on the return click.

```
<Html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="showit">Show More</div>
    <div class="shown" style="display: none;"> 
      Here is some content that I want to display
    </div>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
          var element = document.getElementById("showit");
        
          $('#showit').click(function(){
            $('.shown').slideToggle("fast");
            element.innerHTML = "Show Less";
          });
        });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yxb8681b/)

I am new to JS, can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showit').click(function(){
         $('.shown').slideToggle("fast");
         $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Show Less' ? 'Show More': 'Show Less');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thats great, is there anyway I can add to this by swapping another element from say + to - at the same time in a seperate element?

Comment: So can i change multiple innerHTML elements in the onClick Handler?

Comment: yes, do the same thing in next line eg. $(this).text(...);$(elem).text(...)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to use a flag variable (on/off or true/false in JS):

```
var element = document.getElementById("showit");
var isShown = false;
    $('#showit').click(function(){
        $('.shown').slideToggle("fast");
        isShown = !isShown;                   // flip the flag
        element.innerHTML = isShown ? "Show Less" : "Show More";
    });
```

---

Working fiddle and snippet below:

http://jsfiddle.net/jdwfkwc0/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var element = document.getElementById("showit");
  var isShown = false;
  $('#showit').click(function() {
    $('.shown').slideToggle("fast");
    isShown = !isShown; // flip the flag
    element.innerHTML = isShown ? "Show Less" : "Show More";
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="showit">Show More</div>
<div class="shown" style="display: none;">Here is some content that I want to display</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var element = document.getElementById("showit");

    $('#showit').click(function(){
        var $el = $('.shown'),
            text = $el.is(":visible") ? 'More' : 'Less';
        alert();
        $el.slideToggle("fast");
        element.innerHTML = "Show " + text;
    });

});
```

This is based on whether the div is visible, you is more flexible as you can change the text easily.

Answer (score 0):

Solution could be simple, just add toogleFlag and deal with it:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var element = document.getElementById("showit");
    var elementIsVisible = true;

    $('#showit').click(function(){

        $('.shown').slideToggle("fast");
        toggleText(element);
    });

    function toggleText(element){
        if(elementIsVisible){
            element.innerHTML =  "Show Less";
            elementIsVisible = false;
        }else{
            element.innerHTML =  "Show More";
            elementIsVisible = true;
        }        
    }

});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/DariuszMusielak/yxb8681b/2/